# Space background in opengl C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a solar system and I wanted to have the background filled with stars. What would be the most appropriate way to accomplish this? Is using skybox better then drawing individual pixels?
Any ideas on good tutorials that would help me with either of these? It doesn't have to be realistic. Something simple would work; however I also like to try something more realistic to see how it would look.

Comment: Depends on how realistic you want, a simple texture would work well and is less expensive/time consuming than making it manually

Comment: I'll add more info to my question based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: You could do a simple texture sky box, you could make a cube map, you could make each star a gazillion poly sphere and render from far away, etc.  Lots of choices, but the sky box is probably easiest.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I read some tutorials on skyboxes but I didn't really get it. I mean, I got the concept and how it should work, but I didn't get my code to work with it.

Comment: You could always just do a few point sprites for the stars to begin with on a black background.  That is just a few GL calls to setup.